# Model Relationships Not Working Properly/Loading Instantly

Tags: php, laravel, database, pivot-table, relationship

I'm having issues with retrieving information from the relationships I have setup in my models. It is a Laravel application (Version 10) using php 8.1.

These are my database migrations:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('team_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('current_team_id')->after('id')->default(0);
});
```

This is the current user I have in my “users” table:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `current_team_id`, `name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(100, 0, 'Test User', 'test@test.com', NULL, '$2y$10$JuEirza2w0.9Qv60Hk7f2.CVaG9/WuDzb9qEHYR.BgN/ZviVqqJL.', NULL, '2023-04-21 09:29:24', '2023-04-21 09:29:24');
```

This is the team_user table data:

```
INSERT INTO `team_user` (`team_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 100),
(2, 100);
```

And this is the teams table:

```
INSERT INTO `teams` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Team 1', '2023-04-17 08:46:55', '2023-04-21 09:25:29'),
(2, 'Team 2', '2023-04-17 08:50:10', '2023-04-17 08:50:10');
```

This is my user model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'current_team_id',
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];

public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}
```

This is my team model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Why is it that if I try the following in my User model:

```
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::created(function (User $user) {
        dd($user->teams()->first()->id);
        $user->current_team_id = $user->teams()->first()->id;
    });
}
```

That I get the following response:

```
Attempt to read property "id" on null
```

If I had the following:

```
protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::created(function (User $user) {
            $user = User::find($user->id);

            $teams = $user->teams()->get();

            dd($teams);
        });
    }
```

I get the following:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2026 ▼ // app/Models/User.php:71
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

If instead of finding user by "$user->id" and insert the id of a user that is already stored within the database, I'm able to get the teams associated with that user just fine. I feel like the issue I'm having is that the teams relationship isn't being loaded quickly enough and therefore is returning null.

I would also like to point out that on creation of a new user and assigning the teams to that user, my pivot table appears to store the correct information and assigns the teams to the user as expected.

Let me know if you notice anything obvious and thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, `User $user` followed by `$user = User::find($user->id);`... Why??? `$user` is already a `User` instance from your database, which you're then using the `id` of **to query your database for the exact same `User` instance...** Don't do that.

Comment: The obvious issue here is that you're checking `$user->teams` **immediately after a `User` is created**... But at that point, there wouldn't be anything in the `team_user` pivot table (since the `User` was _literally just created_...) So `$user->teams()->first()` is `null`, and `$user->teams()->get()` is `empty`.

Comment: Is there a way I could delay the search for the user's teams at all? Also, I've updated the teams table insert statement.

Comment: Yeah, you need to look at the chronological order: Create a Team, Create a User, Associate Team and User **OR** Create a User, Create a Team, Associate Team and User; that 3rd step is when `$user->teams` will be not `empty`, but you're checking it on the 1st or 2nd step via `static::created`, so `$user->teams` will always be `empty`. I don't know if there's a model event listener for when a `belongsToMany()` is created, but that would be the correct time to update `$user->current_team_id`.

Comment: The way I have it set up at the moment is that the teams have already been created and added to the "teams" table. Then, when creating a user, I can select multiple teams to be assigned to the user. On creation of the user, I would like to set the "current_team_id" of the user to be the first team associated with the user's "id". I don't know if I'm maybe better trying to set the "current_team_id" for the user at another stage in the process outwith the model. I feel like it would be best/save more time to just have it set the value there and then.

Comment: Yes, but when you create a User, it is not associated with a Team; it can't be, since both need to fully exist for that connection to be made. Your code probably looks something like `$user = User::create(...);` then `$user->teams()->attach(...)` (or similar), but with `static::created`, you're checking `$user->teams` on the `User::create()` step. Do you get what I'm saying? It's not a case of "maybe better trying [...] at another stage in the process", you **need** to do that later in the process, otherwise `$user->teams` will **always be `empty`**.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean. That's why I had changed it from "static::creating" to "static::created" or "static::saved" because I thought the likes of "static::saved" was fired after the model had been saved and therefore the user should be saved and would then be able to reference the teams assigned to that user.

Comment: Yeah, `static::saved` is definitely closer, but you'll still have the same issue if a `save()` is called before the association happens. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-attach-which-event-is-fired?page=1 this might help, as it looks for when the `pivot` table (`team_user`) is updated, but you could also simple do `$user->current_team_id = ...` _outside_ of one of these events.